# FogCreek Kiln Always Gives Error "Your session has expired" On First Try

Tags: kiln

Every time that I do a code review in Kiln, the first time I go to add a comment, approve/reject the review, or close the review, it pops up a dialog box saying,

> **Your session has expired**
>
> You are no longer logged in. Please log in and try your request again.

The words "log in" are hyperlinked, so I click it and type my comment again. Half the time, I forget to re-mark the code. This is the biggest bug in my usage of Kiln.

Is there a way to make this stop happening?

We are on version 2.7.29 of Kiln.

This problem is known on kiln.stackexchange.com, but my account is limited over there. [Here is the question](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/your-session-has-expired-whenever-opening-a-new-browser-instance).

Can someone from FogCreek please provide a status update? This is a bug that we can repeat at will.

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be [emailing them](http://www.fogcreek.com/sendmail.html) to get their attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could get rid of this problem by upgrading

check [this link](http://status.fogcreek.com/2012/06/kiln-on-demand-upgrade-june-26th-0200-utc-june-25th-2200-edt.html)

> We will be performing an account upgrade to Kiln 2.9 on Sunday June 24th at 02:00 UTC
>   ...
>
> - Countless bug fixes and stability improvements, such as:
>
>   - Fix spurious "your session has expired" errors.

Comment: Very good. Just waiting for it to be available for our servers before accepting as the answer.